# Buzzing sounds when I switch off the electrical socket

Tags: electrical

Is it fine to hear buzzing sounds when switching off power points?

I hear this sound occasionally when I switch off my power points.

Comment: Are you talking about receptacles with an on/off switch next to them, like are used in the UK?

Comment: Are you throwing the switch smartly, or are you sort of diddle-daddling and throwing the switch in slow motion?

Comment: I switching it off smartly, not in slow motion.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is it fine to hear buzzing sounds when switching off power points?**

It suggests something is plugged in and turned on (drawing current) and that maybe the switch contacts are not clean or are pitted.

The buzzing sound is probably arcing as the switch breaks the current. Its a sign of further damage accumulating.

New sockets are cheap enough (less than two cups of coffee) that you could try replacing one and see what effect it has.

At a minimum I would turn the circuit off at the breaker and open up the socket to looks for signs of overheating.

Comment: I just had all my electrical rewiring and power points changed few months back.

Comment: @youcanlearnanything: Did you specify a reputable make or did the electrician use the cheapest Chinesium he could find? Try swapping a buzzy one for a non-buzzy one. Still buzzy? I'd still spend £4 and 10mins with a screwdriver to find out. YMMV.

Comment: yes they are reputable. but I have no idea why this is happening.